# ifdown does not recognize interface

Tags: networking, interface

I am trying to use *ifdown* command on my network interface (enp0s3), but it claims, that this interface is not known. When I try the same command with my loopback *lo* it works fine. What could be the problem ?
My network-manager is sure off, only networking daemon is running.

```
lsb_release -d
```

*Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS*

```
cat /etc/netplan/50-cloud.init.yami
```

*[image: emphasized text]*

You should probably know, it is on VM.

Comment: `ifup` and `ifdown` generally only affect interfaces that are declared in `/etc/network/interfaces`. I suspect yours is not. Did you try: `sudo ifconfig enp0s3 down`?

Comment: ifconfig works fine thanks. Even thought I added my interface into _/etc/network/interfaces_ in this form : _auto enp0s3_ it still does not work, and claim unrecognized interface.

Comment: Please add output of `nmcli general status` to your question.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of: `lsb_release -d` and also: `cat /etc/network/interfaces`

Comment: What version Ubuntu? Edit your question with the output of `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`. Report back to @heynnema

Answer (score 1):

You're currently set to use `networkd`, not `NetworkManager`.

`ifup` and `ifdown` and `nmcli` are `NetworkManager` commands.

Remove all modifications to `/etc/network/interfaces`.

You should work with the `ip` command. Type `man ip` for more info.

Here are some example `ip` commands that should work for you...

```
   ip addr
       Shows addresses assigned to all network interfaces.

   ip neigh
       Shows the current neighbor table in kernel.

   ip link set enp0s3 up
       Bring up interface enp0s3.

   ip link set enp0s3 down
       Bring down interface enp0s3.

   ip route
       Show table routes.
```

Minor twit... your /etc/netplan/*.yaml file should look like this... spacing and indentation are very important...

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp0s3:
      addresses: [192.168.0.110/24]
      gateway4: 192.168.0.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
```

Or, if you wish to use NetworkManager...

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

Followed by:

`sudo netplan generate`

`sudo netplan apply`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, that you define the interface `enp0s3` here: `/etc/network/interfaces`.

Comment: This is not a good idea.

Comment: If this interface is not defined in the stated file, the command ifdown won't find it.

Comment: Do you know the syntax of this definition of interface ?

Comment: Depends on your network configuration, but take a look here: https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration
(Configuring the interface manually)

Comment: Yeah, I tried something like this. But after restarting networking service, it show error. "Unknown interface enp0s3".

Comment: And what exaclty did you put in it?  
Something like `iface enp0s3 inet dhcp` should be sufficient :/

Comment: I only put in _auto enp0s3_, and that was enough for that error.

Comment: The user is using netplan, not NetworkManager, so this doesn't apply.